# postgres fulltext index for email

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want get lei4@gmail.com by searching lei4 or gmail.com.

[image: ts_debug]

The first one only have token: email.

What I want is like the second one

Can we parse the email to email, asciiword and host token? any ideas will help.

I already read the tsearch2 guide, reference, etc. can't find the solution.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue using [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)?

Comment: Sorry for late, the sqlfiddle seems not support sql like this. It's not a issue, I think the postgres support this, but I don't know how to?

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution would be to transform email addresses into `local-part at domain-part` before feeding them to the TS parser.

Since `at` is a stop word in english, it will be ignored.

```
=> select to_tsvector('english','lei4 at gmail.com');
      to_tsvector       
------------------------
 'gmail.com':3 'lei4':1
```

So both `lei4` and `gmail.com` are going to be found in this tsvector.

As a side note, `lei+4@gmail.com` is a valid email address and the TS parser is wrong in tokenizing it into four parts.

Comment: The to_tsvector I used when creating index, It's already stored in db, so this way is not ok. I wish is there a config for parser when gin index. Thanks for your reply:)

Comment: @iamsk: even if it was a parser config, it would come into a play when the tsvectors are produced, after that it's too late.